# Can I draw the background of a UINavigationBar as the background of my custom view?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, custom-view

I have a custom view which I would like to look like a UINavigationBar.  Is there a way for me to draw the background the same way a UINavigationBar would?

I don't want to draw an image or a gradient fill that looks *like* a UINavigationBar - I want to use the same library code (if it is public) that a UINavigationBar does to draw its background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `drawRect:` method of a `UINavigationBar` is private - you can't use it to draw the background of your own view.

The easiest way round this would be to take a screen shot, trim the image to nav bar size, add to your project, and then either draw the image in your view's `drawRect:` method, or add a `UIImageView` as a subview of your view.

Alternatively, would it be possible to use a `UIToolbar` instead of your custom view?

Comment: Maybe - this is to fulfil a designer's requirement that we have a navbar-looking thing with buttons in funny places.  I'll mark this as correct, though, since the answer is no.

Answer (score -1):

You could set your view background image and just use an image that has the navigation bar look already filled in.

As far as tapping into whatever the navBar uses to create itself, you are probably out of luck unless you just build a navBar into your app. Otherwise you would end up having to build a custom view at the top of your app, draw everything in manually. At that point, you are probably better off implementing the navBar.